# a choice bit of information -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

From a book called [*Access 2013: The Missing Manual*](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/missingmanuals/access2013mm):

> Queries let you quickly perform an action on a table. Usually, this action involves
>   retrieving **a choice bit of** information (like the 10 top-selling food items at Ed's
>   Roadside Diner or all the purchases you made in a single day). However, you
>   can also use queries to apply changes.

What do you think the author means by *a choice bit of information*? And of course, I'm most interested in understanding the *choice bit* part.

Comment: *choice* is an adjective (easily found in a dictionary). *bit* is a noun (see the dictionary if you do not know what it means)

Comment: One of the definitions of choice as an adjective is "(especially of food) of very good quality." I don't understand the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old phrase that means a small selection out of the whole. In your example, the SQL query will retrieve a specific selection of information out of the database. As shown in that example, the phrase is commonly used in regard to **information**. Another example is "a choice bit of gossip." The phrase also implies that the "choice bit" in question is something **desirable** or **sought after**, like gossip. The database query retrieves information that you want.

However, the phrase is not always used for information. It can be used for anything where a selection can be chosen out of the whole, like with food or land. I found an old newspaper example that features ["a choice bit of land"](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=LcAhAAAAIBAJ&sjid=0pwFAAAAIBAJ&pg=4288%2C4782591AAAIBAJ&pg=4288,4782591). Another old use of the phrase is "a choice bit of calico," meaning a desirable woman.

I should also mention that it's not really a phrase you would use often. It's more for flavor.

Comment: I don't think it is more commonly applied to information than to other things, but I do think you've explained the sense of it well.